# Button momentarily changes color when selected tkinter

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

Is there a best practice for making a tkinter button momentarily change color when it is selected (so the user gets a visual feedback that the button was pressed).

I have read it is not a good idea to use `time.sleep()` in a tkinter GUI.

When my button is pressed, the code happens so fast that even when I have a `button.config()` command to change color, it doesn't occur without using `time.sleep()`

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be what you want:

```
Button(background=normal_color, foreground=text_color,
       activebackground=pressed_color, activeforeground=pressed_text_color)
```

This changes the button from `normal_color` to `pressed_color` when the button is pressed.

It's actually a simple question with a simple answer but I had to look everywhere too. Finally found this answer by reading http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/button.htm.

Answer (score 0):

You can change the color upon clicking, then use the `after` method to reset the color back to the original, after some time has passed

```
import tkinter as tk


def reset_color():
    bt['fg'] = 'black'


def clickme():
    print('clicked')
    bt['fg'] = 'red'
    root.after(2000, reset_color)  # after 2 seconds


root = tk.Tk()
bt = tk.Button(root, text='will color for a while\nafter clicked', command=clickme)
bt.pack()
root.mainloop()
```